# Application_ItemSend in Outlook prevents closing compose window

Tags: vba, outlook

I used Application_ItemSend to modify a signature when a message was sent in Outlook 2010.

The modification does occur, and with the debugger, I verified that it occurs after clicking the Send icon.

The recipient received the modified message, but the compose window remained open with the unmodified message.  (With **no** handler, it closes when Sent.)

A quick search showed some problems with this handler were resolved by deleting the project and creating a new one, somehow causing an old library to be replaced by a new one.  I did that and pasted in the exact same code.  Verified that the correct version of the library was referenced.

Now, the recipient still receive the modified message, and the compose window still remains open.  But now, the message body is erased in the compose window.

What I would like to do is have the compose window go away, like before, but still have the VBA actions (changing the sig) occur.  The VBA used is from http://www.nangets.net/?p=151

I can buy or download other ways to do it, but I prefer this one--simple **and** open source.

Comment: What does your event handler do? Have you tried to comment out all of the code?

Comment: slightly modified version of that code (to use hard-coded string instead of reading a txt file) does not produce the same problem for me. Win 7 Pro, Outlook 2010.  Do you perhaps have other code that is creating a new MailItem object?

Comment: @Dimitry: See the source at the link I included.

Comment: @David: I pasted the VB into a blank module and no other modules existed.

Answer (score 0):

Sigh, I hate when that happens!  After reproducing the unwanted behavior several times, including after exiting and re-launching Outlook, I posted the question.

About nineteen minutes later, I sent another e-mail and it did what it is supposed to do.